# Google Glass Timeline item actions: What are the icon dimensions?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

What are the native image dimensions of the icons specified in 'iconUrl' for a custom timeline item action?

This doesn't appear to be documented yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menuItems's icon should be 50 x 50 pixels and white on transparent according to our documentation on [UI Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/glass/ui-guidelines#creating_menu_items):

> Follow these guidelines when designing your menus:
>
> - If you specify an icon, use a 50x50 pixel image.
> - Limit display names to a few words if possible.
> - Use the default icon and display name for built-in menu items unless you are using the menu item for something very different.

Comment: @Alain does it matter what drawable directory the icon is placed in? mdpi? nodpi?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brief list of the specs to guide your development:

```
Screen aspect ratio
    16x9
Screen resolution
    640 x 360 pixels
Share contact icon size
    640 x 360 pixels
Menu option icon size
    50 x 50 pixels
Supported media format
    Container: MP4
    Video: H.264 baseline and H.263 baseline
    Audio: AAC and MP3
```

[source](https://developers.google.com/glass/ui-guidelines#creating_menu_items)

Answer (score 1):

This is the default css stylesheet used by the timecards :

https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/assets/css/base_style.css

It contains the dimensions of all the elements that can be used in the timecard.