# Google Glass Launcher Icon Size

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, android-icons

I am developing an android application for google glass using GDK. I found that the application is picking up the ic_launcher icon form the hdpi folder i.e. 72x72 pixel icon.

I want to know that is it the recommended icon size for the google glass applications?

Also what are the recommended icon size(72x72,96x96... etc.) and folder(hdpi, mdpi.. etc.) for the menu, sub-menu, activity, timeline icons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Glass Timeline item actions: What are the icon dimensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707691/google-glass-timeline-item-actions-what-are-the-icon-dimensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the list of icon size here.

https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/checklist

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution...

xxhdpi : 144x144 px

xhdpi : 96x96 px

hdpi : 72x72 px

mdpi: 48x48 px

ldpi: 36x36 px

For more details for iconography must go with...

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

For Glass, I think providing hdpi icon is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief list of the specs to guide your development:

```
Screen aspect ratio
    16x9
Screen resolution
    640 x 360 pixels
Share contact icon size
    640 x 360 pixels
Menu option icon size
    50 x 50 pixels
Supported media format
    Container: MP4
    Video: H.264 baseline and H.263 baseline
    Audio: AAC and MP3
```